# How to pass the button ids of an array of buttons to php file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, button

I want to create new buttons using a single button, and after creating those new buttons, I want to click on them and have their id number sent to the php file.

my code:

```
<script>
var count=1;

   document.getElementById("btn").onclick=function(){
      document.getElementById("col").innerHTML+="<tr><td><button type='submit' name='id' id='clickable'>"+count+"</button></td></tr>";
      var cid=count;
      $("#clickable").click(function(){
         location.href="trial29.php?id="+cid;
      });
      count++;
   }

</script>
```

The problem is that I'm not able to make more than one button clickable.
Also I'm not able to set the id of the button to the value they have on them.

Comment: `id` is a __unique__ identifier. Having a lot of items with same id means that only first one will be considered.

Comment: you should use 'on('click',...' as you create those buttons on the fly. Consider adding a **jsfiddle** or describe the error more specifically.

Comment: use a common class instead of id

Comment: thanks! yes using a class worked

Comment: $("#clickable").click(function(){
         location.href="trial29.php?id="+cid;
      });
this block have problem and caused the code to stop that is why the count remain equal 1 and did not increased

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code ...

```
<script>
var count=1;

document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function(){

    document.getElementById("col").innerHTML+="<tr><td><button type='submit' name='id_"+count+"' class='newbtn' id='"+count+"'>"+count+"</button></td></tr>";
    var cid=count;
    count++;
    alert(count)

}

    $(document).on("click", ".newbtn", function(e) {
        var cid = $(this).attr('id');

        alert(cid);
        location.href="trial29.php?id="+cid;
    });

</script>
```